# Wide to long format with dates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with an ID variable, an onset date variable and an end date variable.

```
#Looks like this:


id <- c("1","2","3")
onset <- c("2023-09-12","2023-09-10","2023-09-06")
end <- c("2023-09-12","2023-09-13","2023-09-07")

df <- data_frame(id,onset,end)

df
```

I need to convert this dataframe into long format, with one row for each date comprised in df.
The result should be like this:

```
id <- c("1","2","2","2","2","3","3")
date <- c("2023-09-12","2023-09-10","2023-09-11","2023-09-12","2023-09-13","2023-09-06","2023-09-07")

df_long <- data_frame(id,date)

df
```

Any insight?

I tried `rowwise()` and `unnest()` from dplyr but to no use.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a reshape question so much as it's a question about making a sequence of dates from `onset` to `end` for each value of `id`.  You can use `reframe()` from `dplyr` to do this pretty easily.  First, you'll need to get the date strings into date format, which I did with `lubridate::ymd()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
id <- c("1","2","3")
onset <- c("2023-09-12","2023-09-10","2023-09-06")
end <- c("2023-09-12","2023-09-13","2023-09-07")

df <- data.frame(id,onset,end)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(onset:end, ~lubridate::ymd(.x))) %>% 
  reframe(date = seq(onset, end, by="1 day"))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   id    date      
#>   <chr> <date>    
#> 1 1     2023-09-12
#> 2 2     2023-09-10
#> 3 2     2023-09-11
#> 4 2     2023-09-12
#> 5 2     2023-09-13
#> 6 3     2023-09-06
#> 7 3     2023-09-07
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>